# Google Stackdriver getting Unsuccessful HTTP request 404

Tags: stackdriver

I'm on AWS EC2. While running stackdriver-agent to check the status of the agent I'm getting HTTP request 404.

Stack trace -

> sudo service stackdriver-agent status stackdriver-agent.service - LSB:
>   start and stop Stackdriver Agent    Loaded: loaded
>   (/etc/init.d/stackdriver-agent; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
>   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-03-15 07:15:24 UTC; 34s ago
>        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)   Process: 3732 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/stackdriver-agent stop (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 3754
>   ExecStart=/etc/init.d/stackdriver-agent start (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)
>       Tasks: 12    Memory: 2.1M
>         CPU: 68ms    CGroup: /system.slice/stackdriver-agent.service
>              └─3782 /opt/stackdriver/collectd/sbin/stackdriver-collectd -C /opt/stackdriver/collectd/etc/collectd.conf -P /var/run/stackdriver-agent.pid
>
> Mar 15 07:15:24 ip-10-0-5-248 collectd[3781]: plugin_load: plugin
>   "match_throttle_metadata_keys" successfully loaded. Mar 15 07:15:24
>   ip-10-0-5-248 collectd[3781]: plugin_load: plugin "stackdriver_agent"
>   successfully loaded. Mar 15 07:15:24 ip-10-0-5-248 collectd[3781]:
>   plugin_load: plugin "aggregation" successfully loaded. Mar 15 07:15:24
>   ip-10-0-5-248 stackdriver-agent[3754]:    ...done. Mar 15 07:15:24
>   ip-10-0-5-248 systemd[1]: Started LSB: start and stop Stackdriver
>   Agent. Mar 15 07:15:24 ip-10-0-5-248 collectd[3782]: write_gcm: json
>   credentials parsed successfully.
>   email=stackdriver-agent-authorizatio@myproject-1.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
>   project=log Mar 15 07:15:24 ip-10-0-5-248 collectd[3782]: write_gcm:
>   Unsuccessful HTTP request 404: 
>                                                 
>                                                 
>                                                  
>                                                   404 - Not Found
>
> ## 404 - Not Found
>
> Mar 15 07:15:24 ip-10-0-5-248 collectd[3782]: write_gcm: wg_get_from_metadata_server
>   failed fetching
>   http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/hostname Mar
>   15 07:15:24 ip-10-0-5-248 collectd[3782]: Initialization complete,
>   entering read-loop. Mar 15 07:15:24 ip-10-0-5-248 collectd[3782]:
>   tcpconns plugin: Reading from netlink succeeded. Will use the netlink
>   method from now on.

When I tried to log the exception the message JSON is getting created successfully, however, network exception is raised

> ERROR RawSocketSender:199 - org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>           at org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.connect(RawSocketSender.java:83)
>           at org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.reconnect(RawSocketSender.java:92)
>           at org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.flush(RawSocketSender.java:186)
>           at org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.send(RawSocketSender.java:177)
>           at org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.emit(RawSocketSender.java:147)
>           at org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.emit(RawSocketSender.java:129)
>           at org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.emit(RawSocketSender.java:124)
>           at org.fluentd.logger.FluentLogger.log(FluentLogger.java:101)
>           at org.fluentd.logger.FluentLogger.log(FluentLogger.java:86)
>           at com.rachna.interceptor.RachnaExceptionMappingInterceptor.publishException(RachnaExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:141)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:201)
>           at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:216)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
>           at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
>           at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
>           at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
>           at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
>           at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
>           at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)
>           at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
>           at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
>           at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
>           at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>           at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:868)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1504)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1460)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about two separate problems. The first part is about the Stackdriver **monitoring** agent (which used to be the only Stackdriver agent, hence the unfortunate legacy bit of naming there). The 404 error is actually expected -- it's trying to contact the GCE and AWS metadata servers in turn, and getting the 404 from the GCE one.

The second is an error in communicating with the Stackdriver **logging** agent, about which you've provided no details. The service name is `google-fluentd`, and you should be able to get the service status by running `sudo service google-fluentd status`. It would also help to know the installed package versions for both `google-fluentd` and `google-fluentd-catch-all-config`.

Comment: Not sure what could be the reason. The error was there on Ubuntu 16 + JAVA 8. However, as I moved to Ubuntu 14 + JAVA 7 everything started working. Followed same configuration Steps on both the machine.